# How do you write to a google spreadsheet from a web page (using plain old javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create a simple web page to gather email addresses of people interested in a subject. I have the textbox and button and a javascript function that gets called when they're ready to submit. I don't need to read or visualize the data from the web page, just append each user's email to the google spreadsheet. Is there an easy way to do this? (I don't want to use the built in forms).

Comment: Is using only JavaScript the best way? That way, people will be able to see the entire source code and see your password/api key (I'm presuming Google use the latter, I've never used the spreadsheet api,) which will allow them to spam your spreadsheet. Maybe using PHP or another server side language would be better.